# React hook form returning blank object on submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, react-hook-form

Here's my simplified problem:

https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-fire-mm91r?file=/src/FormWrapper.tsx

And the code:

```
export const FormItemWrapper = ({ children }) => {
  return <FormItem>{children}</FormItem>;
};

export const FormWrapper = ({ children }) => {
  const { handleSubmit } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data); // logs { }
  };
  return <Form onFinish={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>{children}</Form>;
};

export default function App() {
  const { control, watch } = useForm();
  console.log(watch()); // logs { }
  return (
    <FormWrapper>
      <FormItemWrapper>
        <Controller
          control={control}
          name="tmp"
          render={({ field }) => <Input {...field} />}
        />
      </FormItemWrapper>
      <FormItemWrapper>
        <Button htmlType="submit">Save</Button>
      </FormItemWrapper>
    </FormWrapper>
  );
}
```

The problem:

`React-hook-form` doesn't seem to see the data I type in. I can get it using `antd`, but can't with `react-hook-form`. Why? What am I missing?

`watch()` logs only once, and it logs `{ }`. `onSubmit` logs `{ }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have created two different form instances with useForm call. If you want to get current form context inside Controller you should use useFormContext and wrap your form in FormProvider.

Working example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-lehmann-mgd0i?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Sorry, didn't save codepen :( Removed wrong link